# UI-Router. How can I navigate to a page in my project that I don't want to include as a State?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router

I'm still learning Angular and UI-Router... as I pretty much went the UI-Router route because everyone was telling me it's the way to go..

I originally had the login page as part of all the States.. but decided it's best to keep it as a separate stand-alone page

But I can't figure out how to redirect to the Login page...

```
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider
    .otherwise('');

//what i used to have, will remove this
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'Account/Login',
    })..etc
```

so now if i want to redirect to the actual URL now.. how can i go about doing this?

I've tried:

```
$location.url('/Account/Login');
$location.path('/Account/Login');
```

but they just seem to append to the URL.  How can I use UI-Router and go to a page in my project that is not a state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have access to any of the native javascript window methods. Angular provides an injectable reference to it as `$window`

```
$window.location = '/non-angular-url';
// OR
window.location = '/non-angular-url';
```

> **$window:** A reference to the browser's window object. While window is globally available in JavaScript, it causes testability problems, because it is a global variable. In angular we always refer to it through the $window service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for testing.

Comment: ah... what a dumb question lol.  been a long day.  thank you!